# How to create an empty lucene query

Tags: java, lucene

For my Lucene Queries I have some preconditions for security reasons.

```
if isValid()
 return build.parse query
else
 return null
```

I want to replace this **`return null`**. I need something like "empty" query, a query thats will nothing do.

Is there a way to build it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want a query that won't match any documents you should use [`MatchNoDocsQuery`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_4_2/core/org/apache/lucene/search/MatchNoDocsQuery.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of the "prohibit" operator (`-`) for this.

For example:

```
-anything
```

...where the literal text "anything" is used - but you can use *any* literal text you like, here. It could be `apples` or a term which actually does exist in your index.

If you have a default field defined, this will be executed against that default field.

Or you can specify a field in your documents:

```
-body:anything
```

---

*Additional Notes*

How does this work? Why does `-anything` not return any results? Why doesn't it find all results which do not contain the term "anything"?

First, `-anything` forces all documents which *do* contain `anything` to have a score of zero (they are prohibited). But after that has been executed, there are no more clauses in the query. There is no more information for Lucene to use, to determine how any remaining documents should be scored. Therefore all documents remain unscored (they are all effectively 0).

Documents with no score are never returned by a standard query.

The "prohibit" operator is typically used in conjunction with one or more additional query clauses. Here we are using it on its own, which is how we can exploit this behavior.

(You can also use `NOT` as a synonym for `-`.)